# How to get dimensions (i.e. innerWidth) of object inserted into DOM via jQuery.load()

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

On a complex AJAX site I need to retrieve CSS-dimensions of newly inserted DOM objects, i.e. the value of a certain DIVs innerWidth, so I can resize loaded images to their parents dimensions.

I am loading the new Stuff into the DOM via **[jQuery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)**-POST:

```
$( 'DIV#newStuff' ).load( 'insertthis.ajax', {id:1}, function() {
    var iMaxWidth = $( 'DIV#widthNeeded' ).innerWidth();
    console.log(iMaxWidth);
} );
```

**The problem:** FireFox (PaleMoon) 9.2 => returning "442" as expected.
Maxthon 3 and Chrome 17 => returning either "0" or a much higher value "736".
Both on Win7. jQuery 1.7.1

I also tried the jQuery.actual()-plugin with the same results.

*To clearify:* this is a very much simplified extract of the actual function. I'm only trying to show the core problem. The loaded script is plain PHP (I changed the extension to .ajax).

**The solution (workaround):**
Wrapping the success callback code with an additional setTimeout()-function gives some browsers the dire needed time to calculate the newly rendered DOM-stuff's dimensions proberly.

```
$( 'DIV#newStuff' ).load( 'insertthis.ajax', {id:1}, function() {
    setTimeout( function() {
        var iMaxWidth = $( 'DIV#widthNeeded' ).innerWidth();
        console.log(iMaxWidth);
    }, 500 );
} );
```

Comment: what does it have to do with PHP?

Comment: Do you still get the '0' result if you were putting the innerWidth call after the load function (ie outside of the callback, just before you call alert)

Comment: @AshleyDavies No! Worse: I get "null".

Comment: @Gerep Well, the executed code in the .load() is PHP. But you are right, does not need the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your *revised* question:

I can't immediately see why you'd be getting those kinds of discrepancies. It may be that you need to give the browser a moment to reflow or something, by effectively doing a yield, like this:

```
$( 'DIV#newStuff' ).load( 'insertthis.ajax', {id:1}, function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var iWidth = $( 'DIV#widthNeeded' ).innerWidth();
        var jqWidthKeeper = $( 'DIV#widthKeeper' );
        var iMaxWidth = jqWidthKeeper.actual( 'innerWidth' );
        console.log(iMaxWidth);
    }, 0);
} );
```

jQuery calls the `load` callback *immediately* after updating the element. I've sometimes seen browsers need you to give their rendering thread a moment to reflow.

Comment: **Yes! Good solution!** With this workaround I get the same value returned by all browsers. I actually had to set the timeout to 500 ms though, just to be on the safe side. Boy, I hate hacks!!!

Comment: @maxpower9000: Glad that did it! Wow, 500ms.